# Using cocopods with different build environment in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a multiple environment project and created 3 different environments  `dev`, `staging` and `production`. I equally use external libraries and hence use cocoapods and enverything worked well till recently when ever I add a library and run `pod install` the library is added though I have always got warnings like this

> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project
>   because your project already has a custom config set. In order for
>   CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base
>   configurations of the target `XXTests` to `Target Support
>   Files/Pods-XXTests/Pods-XXTests.debug (staging).xcconfig` or include
>   the `Target Support Files/Pods-XXTests/Pods-XXTests.debug
>   (staging).xcconfig` in your build configuration
>   (`XX/Configs/Staging.xcconfig`).

which was no issue execpt for that now, the libraries are not added to `Search Paths` by default and I have to manually add it which is really really weird because I have to add for `dev`, `staging` and `production`

Have in mind, I added pod targets to my `.xcconfig` files and I do not know why this is like this. I have added one of the config file example and my podfile sample

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XX/Pods-XX.release.xcconfig"

ENV = dev
BASE_URL = https:/
ACCOUNT_URL = https:/$

// App Settings
APP_NAME = XX (dev)
APP_BUNDLE_ID = co.xx.dev
```

my pod file looks like this

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'XX' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Material'

  target 'XXTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'XXUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

What could I do to make libraries add to path  so i could import them.

This was the guide I used in setting up my environment.

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/let-s-setup-your-ios-environments